# Не ищет по регулярному выражению

Tags: python, регулярные-выражения

Есть строка, полученная из внешнего API, которая является регулярным выражением `^([\u0030-\u0039\u0061-\u007A\u002D]+)$`

Это на самом деле `^([0-9a-z-]+)$`

Я хочу использовать его как регулярное выражение

```py
regex = "^([\u0030-\u0039\u0061-\u007A\u002D]+)$"
string = "hello"
res = re.match (regex, string)
if res:
    print("YES")
```

Я пытался преобразовать в байты, использовать это регулярное выражение напрямую, различные варианты `encode()` и `decode()` не работают

python >= 3.6

Comment: Вообще-то эта регулярка, если переводить с юникода, выглядит как `^([0-9а-яё-]+)$`, т.е. с кириллицей. Вы точно уверены, что нужны латинские буквы?

Comment: согласен, ошибся с регуляркой вот такая `^([\u0030-\u0039\u0061-\u007A\u002D]+)$`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

По идее можно это выражение преобразовать из юникода при помощи `encode()` и `decode`, только использовать их нужно вместе и друг за другом, т.е. сразу после системной шифровки нужно расшифровать её в качестве последовательности байтов с использованием `unicode_escape` — мы же из юникод-символов переводим.

```py
regex = "^([\u0030-\u0039\u0061-\u007A\u002D]+)$"

new_regex = regex.encode().decode('unicode-escape')
print(new_regex) # ^([0-9a-z-]+)$
```

Comment: Спасибо большое, это помогло, сутки мучался